# Error On Show Matched Values From Google Sheet To Web App

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hey I'm trying to show a row of values from Google Sheet when the user input a specific code number. But I got an error in my .gs:

> TypeError: codeList.IndexOf is not a function

And error in my console:

> Uncaught at getTable

Here's my .html code:

```
  document.getElementById("codeInput").addEventListener("input",getData);
  function getData(){
  var code = document.getElementById("codeInput").value;
    if(code.length === 5){
       google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(view).getTable(code);   
    } 
  }

  function view(array){
    var tbody = document.getElementById("table-body");

    var row = document.createElement("tr");
    var col1 = document.createElement("td");
    col1.textContent = array[0];
    var col2 = document.createElement("td");
    col2.textContent = array[1];
    var col3 = document.createElement("td");
    col3.textContent = array[2];
    row.appendChild(col1);
    row.appendChild(col2);
    row.appendChild(col3);
    tbody.appendChild(row); 
  }
```

And here's my .gs code:

```
function getTable(code){
   var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Nh-CCXayaQ8YFuxV76MGnWiAF2rgcxf5bCJwJWvy_-s/edit#gid=0";
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
   var ws = ss.getSheetByName("IPP Gol I-III");
   var data = ws.getRange(2, 1, ws.getLastRow()-1, 4).getValues();

   var codeList = data.map(function(r){return r[1]; });
   var submissionList = data.map(function(r){return r[0]; });
   var nameList = data.map(function(r){return r[2]; });
   var emailList = data.map(function(r){return r[3]; });

   var position = codeList.IndexOf(code);

   var array = [submissionList[position],nameList[position],emailList[position]];

   if(position > -1){
      return array;
   }else{
      return 'Unavailable';
   }                     
}
```

Your response would be very appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Oh sorry, will post another one.. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `var position = codeList.IndexOf(code);` is supposed to be written like this `var position = codeList.indexOf(code);` case matters in Google Apps Script and JavaScript.

Comment: Gosh its only the matter of case haha now the error is gone. Thank you!